# How do I get forms authentication in silverlight to be more resilient?

Tags: silverlight, forms-authentication

I have a silverlight application backed by RIA services & EntityFramework. Users log in directly in the silverlight application. We have the `[RequiresAuthentication]` attribute on the DomainService and have implemented custom `MembershipProvider`/`AuthenticationBase<UserBase>` for custom authentication utilizing "forms authentication". All of this is working well to authenticate users.

The problem is that users with laptops using wifi will travel through the building and hand off between wifi access points. As soon as that handoff occurs, the users session is immediately terminated - with no notice to the user. I would like some way to make the session more resilient. Asp.Net's out-of-the-box forms authentication seems to do this well - as long as you are inside the session timeout and you haven't deleted your cookies, you are good to go regardless of any temporary connectivity issues. What can I do to get my Silverlight app to be at least as resilient as a standard asp.net app?

One thing that might be the issue, is that I haven't implemented many of the functions in the MembershipProvider - really only `ApplicatinName` and `ValidateUser()`. Could that be the source of my problem?